# using docker and mysql to import the file?

Tags: mysql, docker

I am using a mysql docker container to load the database data， the database folder containers multiple files shown as

[image]

employees.sql has the following commands

```
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_emp.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_manager' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_manager.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING titles' as 'INFO';
source load_titles.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
source load_salaries1.dump ;
source load_salaries2.dump ;
source load_salaries3.dump ;
```

right now I am using the docker to do so with the following orders.

1. First, check and copy the container ID for your MySQL docker by:

   ```
   sudo docker ps 

   docker id is 3a66701bd013, name is mysql
   ```
2. Copy the SQL dump file directory and the file into the container using:

   docker cp /Users/xisizhe/Downloads/test_db-master/ mysql:/
3. Now to interact with MySQL inside a running container run the following command:

   docker exec -it mysql mysql -uroot -p
4. Now import the file by typing:

   source employees.sql

it works to import employees.sql, but it fails to import the other sql files and dump files.

```
ERROR: 
Failed to open file 'load_salaries1.dump', error: 2
ERROR: 
Failed to open file 'load_salaries2.dump', error: 2
ERROR: 
Failed to open file 'load_salaries3.dump', error: 2
ERROR: 
Failed to open file 'show_elapsed.sql', error: 2
```

any problems for my procedure?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you triedo o debug the problem? Have you checked whether the files exists at the expected locations?

Comment: the files are all in the directory

Comment: If your MySQL container has published a port out to the host (`docker run -p`, Docker Compose `ports:` option) and you have the `mysql` command-line client locally, you can use that directly, which could be cleaner than this multiple-`docker` path.  Loading the dump at startup time using the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` mechanism could also be a good path.

Answer (score 1):

if you execute the following command

```
docker cp /Users/xisizhe/Downloads/test_db-master/ mysql:/
```

you should add the /test_db-master/ before those dump files inside the employees.sql like:

```
source /test_db-master/load_departments.dump ;
source /test_db-master/load_employees.dump ;
...
```

Then, you can import the sql data using the commands:

```
docker exec -i mysql mysql -uroot -p1234  < employees.sql
```